# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{x^2+a^2}{x^4+b^2x^2+b^4}dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\dfrac{x^2+a^2}{x^4+b^2x^2+b^4}dx$$

I tried to simplify this fraction. I noticed that $x^4+b^2x^2+b^4$ can be written as
$$\dfrac{x^6-b^6}{x^2-b^2}$$
Then limit will be
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\dfrac{\left(x^2+a^2\right)\left(x^2-b^2\right)}{x^6-b^6}dx$$
But what next? Is it possible to more simplify this fraction? Can we find indefinite integral of this fraction first?

Comment: Such integral can be computed through the residue theorem. Just dig a bit to find similar questions on MSE.

Comment: For residue method: Since the integrand has nothing special to do with the value zero, first replace $\int_0^{+\infty}$ by $(1/2)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple does the indefinite integral in terms of arctangents and logarithms.  So, **yes**, you can do it by partial fractions, where you first factor the denominator ... to factor it, complete the square, so it becomes a difference of squares

Then take limit to get the answer.  Maple says:
$$
\frac{(a^2+b^2)\pi}{b^3 2\sqrt{3}}
$$
assuming $b > 0$.

Comment: This is same result as in my book, but Mathematica doesn't agree. It say's that answer is $\dfrac{i\pi}{2b^3}\left(a^2-b^2\right)$.

Comment: Oh no!  Say it ain't so!  A bug in Mathematica????

Comment: @Mathematician171: *Mathematica doesn't agree* - It would, if you'd use `Simplify[...]` , and add the conditions $a>0$ and $b>0$.